# Merge Function in R based on Two Columns?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two data frames like such.

```
Table1
Sample Name Position A B C 
1      J    23       x x x
1      K    24       y y y
1      L    25       z z z


Table2
Sample Name Position A B C 
2      M    33       x x x
2      N    34       y y y
2      O    35       z z z
```

I want the final table to look like this.

```
 FinalTable1
Sample Name Position A B C Sample Name Position A B C
1      J    23       x x x 2      J    23       Na Na Na
1      K    24       y y y 2      K    24       Na Na Na
1      L    25       z z z 2      L    25       Na Na Na 
Sample Name Position A B C Sample Name Position A B C
1      M    33       Na Na Na 2      M    33       0 0 0 
1      N    34       Na Na Na 2      N    34       0 0 0
1      O    35       Na Na Na 2      O    35       0 0 0
```

Basically, I want to merge two data frames, so the union of both data frames in terms of Names and Positions, is in the final table, and that the final data frame fills in nonexisting positions with Na, in samples that don't have those genes/positions, but matches samples that do (so if both table1 and table2 had a P and data for it, then they would be written side by side). Eventually, I want to merge 8 data tables like this. I've been trying to play with merge on R, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any guidance would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
cbind(
   merge(tbl1, tbl2, by=c('Name', 'Position'), all.x=TRUE),
   merge(tbl1, tbl2, by=c('Name', 'Position'), all.y=TRUE))
```

If there are multiple datasets to be merged, you can put them in a `list` and then use `Reduce` along with `merge`.  For example

```
lst <- list(tbl1, tbl2)
res1 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=c('Name', 'Position'), 
              all.x=TRUE), lst)

res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=c('Name', 'Position'), 
              all.y=TRUE), lst)
cbind(res1,res2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, when I use the Reduce function, with three tables, of different length, it doesn't give me all the values for tabl2. Ideally, all the values of tabl1 should be there with either a match or NA in table2, and tabl3, and same for table2, and table3, however, all the values for table1 is there, all the values for table3 are there, but not for table2. In other words, I get the result I want when I use your first method twice (once to combine tabl1 and tabl2, and then once again to combine that result with tabl3). I was wondering if you had a solution to this?

Comment: I did anticipate this question.  Could you update your post with datasets that give different lengths?  It would be easier to code.  Another question is why do you need to convert to `wide` format.  I would imagine the `long` form to give more info and easier to check the results.